# Assign column to dataframe with different lengths

Tags: python, pandas

I have a single column and single row pandas dataframe ("valueFlussname") that I want to assign to all the rows in a different dataframe (df) that is 1802 rows x 10 columns.

```
df = df.assign(Flussname = value_flussname)
```

gives me a "Length of values does not match length of index".

How can I assign the value in the "valueFlussname" dataframe to all the rows of the "df" dataframe in a new Column named "Flussname"?

```
df = pd.read_excel('//client/Y$/Risikomanagement/Flussvermessung/ALD/Profile/Tabelle/QP_Aare_267234_269910_022019.xlsx', header=5)
value_flussname = (pd.read_excel('//client/Y$/Risikomanagement/Flussvermessung/ALD/Profile/Tabelle/QP_Aare_267234_269910_022019.xlsx', skiprows = 0, nrows = 1, header = None))
value_flussname = value_flussname.drop(columns=[0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
value_flussname = value_flussname.values[0]
df = df.assign(Flussname = value_flussname)
```

Thank you,

Davide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
df = df.assign(Flussname = valueFlussname.values[0][0])
```

With `valueFlussname` your dataframe.

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @Dedder, can you share a minimal reproducible example? It sounds like your `vaueFlussname` is not a DataFrame like you said it is. If it's already a numpy ndarray, just use `valueFlussname[0][0]`.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Dedder. As far as I know, dataframe has attribute `.values` !
Sharing any other input could help debug your code

Comment: You are right...if i do print(value_Flussname) i get ['Aare']. How to i pass this value?

Comment: Assign the first element of this list then.

`df = df.assign(Flussname = value_Flussname[0])`